# GroupJoin always evaluating locally

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-core, linq-to-entities

I have a linq query that uses GroupJoin and is always evaluating locally causing to hit SQL server n times where n is # of orders.

I have 3 tables Orders, OrderStatus, OrderStatusCode.

```
Orders has OrderId, CustomerId, ProductId
OrderStatus has OrderId, OrderStatusId, OrderStatusCodeId,
OrderStatusCode has OrderStatusCodeId, OrderStatusCodeName

OrderId, CustomerId, ProductId
1         5000       100
2         5400       100

OrderId, OrderStatusId, OrderStatusCodeId  CreatedDateTime
1        1              1 -- started        12/01/2019
1        2              2 -- completed      12/01/2019
1        3              3 -- shipped        12/03/2019

2        1              1 -- started        12/01/2019
2        2              4 -- canceled       12/01/2019
2        3              5 -- refunded       12/10/2019

OrderStatusCodeId, OrderStatusCodeName
1                  started
2                  completed
3                  shipped
4                  canceled
5                  refunded 




    var OrderWithLatestStatus = _dbContext.Orders.Include(h => 
                         h.OrderStatus).ThenInclude(hs => hs.OrderStatusCode)
                        .Where(o => o.ProductId == "100")
                        .GroupJoin(_dbContext.OrderStatus,
                            order => order.OrderId,
                            status => status.OrderId,
                            (o, g) => new 
                            {
                                Order = o,
                                OrderStatuses = g
                            })
                        .Select(x => new EvalWithStatus
                        {
                            OrderId = x.Order.OrderId,
                            CustomerId = x.Order.CustomerId, 
                            AllStatuses = x.OrderStatuses,
                            LatestOrderStatusCodeName = x.OrderStatuses.Any() ? 
                              x.OrderStatuses.Any(s => 
                           s.OrderStatusCode.OrderStatusCodeName.Equals("Canceled")) 
                ? x.OrderStatuses.FirstOrDefault(s => 
                   s.OrderStatusCode.OrderStatusCodeName.Equals("Canceled"))
                  .OrderStatusCode.OrderStatusCodeName :  
                   x.OrderStatuses.OrderByDescending(s => 
                    s.CreatedDateTime).FirstOrDefault()
                    .OrderStatusCode.OrderStatusCodeName 
                     : "Unknown"
```

}

Inside select I'm expecting the latest status to show cancelled for cancelled orders and the actual latest status for completed items

```
OrderId, CustomerId, AllStatuses,              LatestOrderStatusCodeName
1        5000        IEnuerable<OrderStatus>   Shipped
2        5400        IEnuerable<OrderStatus>   Canceled
```

The linq query says it can't evaluate x.OrderStatuses.Any() so it will be evaluated locally causing two separate calls to the database.

What could be changed in the query to make it evaluate on the server?

Comment: Thanks for looking into my question, what could I change to make it run on the server since I don't want it go to server 100 times if there are 100 orders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with this query.

First, it's using projection, so `Include` / `ThenInclude` are redundant they are [ignored](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#ignored-includes) and normally logged as warning, but also can be configured to throw exception.

Second, and that's the main issue is mixing the manual joins and navigation properties. According to the includes, you have the proper navigation properties, so you should not use manual joins at all - *reference* navigation property represents a `join` (`left` or `inner` depending on whether it's `required* or *optional*) and *collection* navigation property represents a`group join`.

In your case, `Order.OrderStatus` property (it should have been called `OrderStatuses`) represents exactly the `OrderStatuses` from your `GroupJoin`.

So simply replacing the `GroupJoin` with

```
.Select(o => new { Order = o, OrderStatuses = o.OrderStatus })
```

or using it directly in the final projection will solve the client evaluation.

However, you can do it better. All these `Any` / `FirstOrDefault` even with server evaluation cause several SQL subqueries to related tables. They can be trimmed down to single `TOP 1` subquery using a proper ordering, e.g.

```
var OrderWithLatestStatus = _dbContext.Orders
    .Select(order => new EvalWithStatus
    {
        OrderId = order.OrderId,
        CustomerId = order.CustomerId,
        AllStatuses = order.OrderStatus.ToList(),
        LatestOrderStatus = order.OrderStatus
            .OrderBy(s => s.OrderStatusCode.OrderStatusCodeName == "canceled" ? 0 : 1)
            .ThenByDescending(s => s.CreatedDateTime)
            .Select(s => s.OrderStatusCode.OrderStatusCodeName)
            .FirstOrDefault() ?? "Unknown"
    });
```

Also note `ToList()` call here

```
AllStatuses = order.OrderStatus.ToList(),
```

This is to opt-in for EF Core 2.1 [Optimization of correlated subqueries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1#optimization-of-correlated-subqueries) and eliminates the N + 1 query problem with such data.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much, makes total sense, would have never thought of using OrderBy in this way. One question though, I did not use ToList() and still it does only one query

Comment: The second query will be evaluated lazily when you access some of the returned object `AllStatuses`. You`d better not experiment with this, it is an "official" recommendation :)